# Is a birational, proper and flat morphism of two noetherian integral schemes an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume that $X,Y$ are two noetherian integral schemes. When the morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is birational, proper and flat, I want to figure out if $f$ is an isomorphism.

I have fonud some materials related using Zariski's Main Theorem. But they need other conditions. I also want to know the relationship between my question and ZMT. (if it's right)

Answer (score 0):

Let me also assume that $f$ is projective. Then the standard argument shows that $f$ is the blowup of an ideal that can be constructed as
$$
I = f_*(L),
$$
where $L$ is a line bundle on $X$ sufficiently ample over $Y$. But if $f$ is flat, the pushforward of a sufficiently ample line bundle is locally free, thus $f$ is the blowup of an invertible ideal. Finally, if $I$ is invertible, the graded algebra
$$
\mathcal{O}_Y \oplus I \oplus I^2 \oplus \dots
$$
is locally isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_Y[t]$, hence its projective spectrum (the blowup of $I$) is isomorphic to $Y$.

Comment: So you prove that f is an isomorphism when f is projective. How about my original case?